# Не подставляется значение в представление через windows forms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server

Существует таблица Заказ, имеющая следующую структуру:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Заказ](
    [IDзаказа] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDкурьера] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDклиента] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDадресата] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDдоставки] [int] NOT NULL,
    [НомерЗаказа] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Вес] [float] NULL,
    [МанипуляционныйЗнак] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Комментарий] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ВидДоставки] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ДатаОформления] [date] NOT NULL,
    [ДатаИсполнения] [date] NOT NULL
```

В windows forms создается форма, где данные этой таблицы представлены с неким изменением через созданное представление: ID людей заменены на их ФИО из соответствующих таблиц (пример: IDкурьера - ФИОкурьера из таблицы Курьер) ФИО выбираются из комбобоксов

Представление имеет следующую структуру:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NewOrder]
    @id_order INT OUTPUT, @id_courier INT OUTPUT, @fio_courier VARCHAR(50), @id_client INT OUTPUT, @fio_client VARCHAR(50), @id_adresat INT OUTPUT, @fio_adresat VARCHAR(50), 
    @id_delivery INT OUTPUT, @number INT, @weight FLOAT, @sign VARCHAR(50), @comment VARCHAR(100), @kind_delivery VARCHAR(20), @reg_date DATE, @exec_date DATE, @res INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT НомерЗаказа FROM Заказ WHERE НомерЗаказа = @number)
        BEGIN
                SET @id_order = (SELECT MAX(IDзаказа)+1 FROM Заказ)
                SET @id_courier = (SELECT IDкурьера FROM Курьер WHERE ФИО = @fio_courier)
                SET @id_client = (SELECT IDклиента FROM Клиент WHERE ФИО = @fio_client)
                SET @id_adresat = (SELECT IDадресата FROM Адресат WHERE ФИО = @fio_adresat)
                SET @id_delivery = (SELECT IDдоставки FROM Доставка WHERE ВидДоставки = @kind_delivery)
                INSERT INTO Заказ VALUES (@id_order, @id_courier, @id_client, @id_adresat, @id_delivery, @number, @weight, @sign, @comment, @kind_delivery, @reg_date, @exec_date)
                SET @res = 1
        END
    ELSE
        SET @res = 0
END
```

Но при работе с формой, при подставлении значений, вылезает исключение **"Не удалось вставить значение NULL в столбец "IDкурьера", таблицы "Chi.dbo.Заказ"; в столбце запрещены значения NULL. Ошибка в INSERT.Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано."**
Коллекция в sqlcommand и само подключение настроены верно (все переменные с собачкой, инпуты и аутпуты прописаны).
Код C#:

```
myCommand.Connection = mySqlConnection;
                myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                
                myCommand.Parameters["@fio_courier"].Value = comboBoxCourier.SelectedValue;
                myCommand.Parameters["@fio_client"].Value = comboBoxClient.SelectedValue;
                myCommand.Parameters["@fio_adresat"].Value = comboBoxAdresat.SelectedValue;
                myCommand.Parameters["@weight"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtWeight.Text);
                myCommand.Parameters["@number"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumber.Text);
                myCommand.Parameters["@sign"].Value = txtSign.Text;
                myCommand.Parameters["@comment"].Value = txtCom.Text;
                myCommand.Parameters["@kind_delivery"].Value = comboBoxKind.SelectedValue;
                myCommand.Parameters["@reg_date"].Value = dateTimePickerReg.Value;
                myCommand.Parameters["@exec_date"].Value = dateTimePickerExec.Value;

                mySqlConnection.Open();
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                mySqlConnection.Close();

                int result = (int)myCommand.Parameters["@res"].Value;
                if (result == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Заказ успешно добавлен!");
                }
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Что-то пошло не так... Проверьте таблицу и повторите действие, если потребуется.");
                }
```

Почему так происходит и как решить данную проблему? уже что только не пробовала, быть может глаза не замечают чего-то простого? очень прошу, помогите

Comment: вижу, что написано, что ошибка в инсёрте, но я каждое поле перед ним пробивала отдельно с данными из таблицы, да даже отдельно в sql server это представление прогоняла - все работает. проблема, видимо в соединении бд с формой, либо в параметрах, но я не понимаю что именно

Comment: Выглядит как `@id_courier = (SELECT IDкурьера FROM Курьер WHERE ФИО = @fio_courier)` возвращает NULL

Comment: да, это я поняла, но я проверяла отдельно эту строку, где перед ним вбивала @fio_courier с каким-то значением и все правильно подставлялось

Comment: Еще Primary key не следует задавать вручную. Его должна назначать сама БД, назначьте первичный ключ, поставьте ему в таблице Auto increment и уберите из запроса. В каждой таблице должен быть первичный ключ, по этому ключу можно связывать таблицы.

Comment: повторюсь, отдельно в sql server запрос корректно работает, даже без изменений в представлении

Comment: я не могу убрать id из таблиц, так как это будет противоречить уже ранее написанной пояснительной записке к курсовому проекту

Comment: Разве я что-то сказал про убирание из таблицы?

Comment: окей. вы про id курьера сейчас выше написали?

Comment: _sql server не позволяет мне изменять структуры таблиц_ - это очень странно, и наверняка решаемо. Я говорил про убирание из запроса id заказа и назначение id заказа базой автоматически через автоинкремент, только и всего. Вы про первичные ключи в таблицах слышали? Где они у вас?

Comment: Почему NULL, я не знаю, возможно опечатка в фио или пробел лишний затесался, или с кодировками проблемы. Отладочные данные видите только вы.

Comment: первичные ключи установлены , просто не вынесла их сюда, по всей видимости

я понимаю, если бы была опечатка, но я миллион раз уже прогоняла программу и ошибка все та же

Comment: Здесь нет никакой магии, о чем ошибка говорит, то и происходит.

Comment: то есть со всей остальной частью (касаемо кода c# ) все вроде как без ошибок?

Comment: Вроде как да. Только я бы на вашем месте из процедуры возвращал ID созданного заказа и делал ExecuteScalar, тогда без дополнительных запросов в базу можно было бы эти данные напрямую закинуть в интерфейс. Так, чисто для удобства.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что эти строки комбобоксов, а именно:

```
myCommand.Parameters["@id_courier"].Value = comboBoxCourier.SelectedValue;
myCommand.Parameters["@id_client"].Value = comboBoxClient.SelectedValue;
myCommand.Parameters["@id_adresat"].Value = comboBoxAdresat.SelectedValue;
```

возвращали не ФИО (которые в них высвечивались), а как раз нужные мне IDшники

Comment: Отладка - сила. А вообще типы значений параметрам надо прямо в C# коде задавать `.Parameters.Add(<name>, <dbtype>).Value = ...`, тогда таких сюрпризов получится избежать.